# How to ship non-elixir files with mix package?

Tags: xml, erlang, elixir, dtd

I'm building a library in Elixir which processes XML-files of some kind. I'd like to ship DTD schema with it, cause that XML-files refer to it inside of `<!DOCTYPE>`. How do I do so that it all worked being imported by another app.

Generalizing: how do I ship some static non-elixir files (resources) that are being used by mix project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual place to put non-source code files that are required at runtime is the `/priv` directory at the root of the package alongside `/lib` or `/config`. The compiler maintains the proper references and makes sure the directory is always available in the appropriate place when accessed through:

```
Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/path/to/file")
```